# Reading file to String in Java results in invisible characters

Tags: java, string, file

I'm having trouble around reading from a text file into a String in Java.  I have a text file (created in Eclipse, if that matters) that contains a short amount of text -- approximately 98 characters.  Reading that file to a String via several methods results in a String that is quite a bit longer -- 1621 characters.  All but the relevant 98 are invisible in the debugger/console.

I've tried the following methods to load the String:

apache commons-io:

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(path));

FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(path), "UTF-8");

byte[] b = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(path);
new String(b, "UTF-8");

byte[] b = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(path);
Charset.defaultCharset().decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)).toString();
```

NIO:

```
new String(Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

And so on.

Is there a method to strip away these control chars?  Is there a way to read files to strings that doesn't have this issue?

---

As noted in the comments below, this behavior is due to a corrupted(?) file generated by Eclipse.  I'd still be interested in hearing any strategies for trimming away control characters from Strings, though!

Comment: If it's an actual text file, there shouldn't be any "control characters", so I might check all assumptions first. For me, eclipse text files are just that, text.

Comment: have you tried opening it with a hex editor?

Comment: @DaveNewton, good suggestion.  I think it is a fluke.  Some combination of using the Eclipse New > Other > General > file dialog, naming it a .csv file, and having LibreOffice as my default csv editor seems to cause it.  Creating the file differently makes the problem go away.  Guess I'll submit an Eclipse bug report!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to strip out all non-printable characters, try this

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{Graph}\n\r\t ]", "");
```

The regex matches all "invisible" characters, except ones we want to keep; in this case newline chars, tabs and spaces.

`\p{Graph}` is a [POSIX character class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions#Character_classes) for all printable/visible characters. To negate a POSIX character class, we can use capital `P`, ie `P{Graph}` (all non-printable/invisible characters), however we need to not exclude newlines etc, so we need `[^\\p{Graph}\n\r\t]` .

Comment: This did work -- though it has the regrettable consequence of stripping away some useful chars like carriage returns and spaces.  But it's in the right direction.

Comment: Well, that's easily fixed: Just add the other characters you want to keep to the character class. I've put in line feeds, carriage returns, tabs and spaces - you can add others ass needed, just follow the example. See edited answer.

Comment: @Omid A ? probably means it's a *visible* charaxcter, but notepad doesn't have a code point for it. This question was about removing *invisible* characters.

Comment: @Bohemian I'm use string.trim().replace("\ufeff", "").

Comment: @omid that will only remove that specific character, not other unprintable characters

Comment: @Bohemian can you please break down the regex, I am not satisfied with the explanation of \\p{Graph} explanation given by regex https://regex101.com/ site.

Comment: @lordvidex see additional explanation in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Read it line by line into a StringBuilder, and then convert it to a String:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
while (true)
{
    String line = file.readLine();
    if (line == null)
        break;
    sb.append(line+"\n");
}
file.close();
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: As I noted above, this behavior is a fluke.. but I tried your suggestion anyway.  Under those same circumstances, it has the same results as the other methods.  i.e. it gives more than a thousand invisible chars.